# PG::ForeignKeyViolation When deleting categories/labels in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord, activeadmin

I'm using `Active Admin` so the `adminuser`can create/delete categories, labels and products.

I can create `Labels`, `Categories`and `Products` with out any problems but when I want to delete Labels or Categories I always get this error:

`PG::ForeignKeyViolation at /admin/labels/2`

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "labels" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_5a55c39b94" on table "products"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "products".
```

And if I try to destroy product I get this flash message `Product could not be destroyed.`

It seems to me that I'm getting this error when I delete `labels` or `categories`that are assigned to product.

I'm not sure what to do to fix it

Below is the relevant code

`app/admin/product.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

permit_params :title, :description, :image, :price_usd, :price_isl, :category_id, :label_id

index do
    column :title
    column :category
    column :label
    column :created_at

    column :price_isk, :sortable => :price_isl do |product|
        number_to_currency(product.price_isl, :unit => "ISK " , :precision => 0) 
    end
    column :price_euro, :sortable => :price_usd do |product|
        number_to_currency(product.price_usd, :unit => "€ " , :precision => 0)
    end

    actions
 end
end
```

`app/admin/label.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Label do
 permit_params :name
end
```

`app/admin/category.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
 permit_params :name
end
```

And in the `app/models/product.rb`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :label

has_many :product_item

before_destroy :ensure_not_product_item

    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, :price_isl, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true

 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

 def ensure_not_product_item
    if product_item.empty?
        return true
    else
        errors.add(:base, 'You have Product Items')
        return false
    end

 end
end
```

and the `app/models/label.rb`

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :pages
end
```

and the `app/models/category.rb`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :products
end
```

and the `app/models/product_items.rb`

```
class ProductItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :cart
 belongs_to :order


 def total_price_usd
    product.price_usd * quantity
 end

 def total_price_isl
    product.price_isl * quantity
 end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to update your `has_many` associations to tell ActiveRecord what to do when you destroy a `Label` or `Category`. Sounds like you want to simply nullify the `label_id` or `category_id` in the associated `Product`s so:

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :dependent => :nullify
  has_many :pages
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :products, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

Not sure what you want to do about `Page`s when you destroy a `Label`, if you want to update them to have no `label_id` then:

```
has_many :pages, :dependent => :nullify
```

if you want to destroy the `Page`s then:

```
has_many :pages, :dependent => :destroy
```

Similarly for the `has_many :product_item` in `Product`. If you want destroy the items while destroying the product then:

1. Drop the `before_destroy :ensure_not_product_item` and the `ensure_not_product_item` method.
2. Update the association to `has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy`.

If you want to make them manually destroy the items before the product then leave what you have in place.

---

The underlying problem is that you have a foreign key constraint inside the database to ensure that the `products.label_id` and `products.category_id` columns always reference valid `categories.id` values. If you delete a row from `categories` (i.e. destroy a `Category` instance) but there are rows in `products` that still reference that category then the database complains because you're trying to violate the foreign key constraint and leave broken data inside your database.

The FK inside the database is a good idea because it keeps you from having broken references in your database but you need to properly clean up.

Comment: This is great.... but what about the `Product could not be destroyed.`message when I try to destroy Products, not labels or caategories?

Comment: You probably want to drop the `before_destroy :ensure_not_product_item` and say `has_many :product_item, :dependent => :destroy`. That would destroy the items when you destroy a product. That's just a guess though, the real solution depends on your business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the label_id or category_id in the product table to nil when you delete the category.  Off the top of my head, but maybe something like:

Category Model:

```
before_destroy :remove_category_from_products

private

def remove_category_from_products
  Product.where(category_id: id).update_all(category_id: nil)  
end
```

I mean, I don't have much context on the business logic in your app, but this should make it so you don't see that error anymore...

Comment: I get it, but not...if I Add this to the model I get this error now : `uninitialized constant Category::Products` in this line `Products.where(category_id: id).update_all(category_id: nil)  `

Comment: And the `before_delete`should be `before_destroy`:)

Comment: crap, it should be Product, not Products `Product.where(category_id: id).update_all(category_id: nil)`

Comment: Sweat... it works perfectly :) But I´m still getting the `Product could not be destroyed.`message if I try to destroy product

Comment: I think the Product could not be destroyed has something to do with the logic in this `ensure_not_product_item`

Comment: Yeah probably, I added the `product_items.rb`to the question... Maybe adding `dependencies` would make it work?

Comment: Before this conversation gets too long, if you were happy with my solution, could you select it, and then make another question about the other problem?  That way everythng is contained in the proper threads